# npm installation of any package hangs

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

Whenever I try to install any npm package in react native project, it hangs at **remove:@babel/core**

[cmd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4I3v.png)

I'm trying to install dropdown package into my react native project but it hangs indefinitely

Following is my package.json file:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.14.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.0-next.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.3",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `package-lock.json`
2. Remove `node_modules`
3. Run `npm install` again